# MVC Razor view need to update controls with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC website using Razor views. My Model is a `List<Device>`. In this particular view I need to enter a serial number for the device's box and, if it matches the device's serial number, change the dropdown enum from `LabelPack` to `SystemPack`. Finally, the controller will update the device's status in the DB.
Here is the relevant code from the view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SerialNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id=@item.SerialNumber name=@item.SerialNumber oninput="return boxSerialNumberInput(@item.SerialNumber)" />
        </td>
        <td>

            <div class="col-md-10" id="@item.SerialNumber">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My question is basically: How do I check if the input serial number matches the device's serial number and update the dropdown? I assume there is a way to do this with JavaScript so I am calling a JavaScript method with the `onInput` event. However, I don't know what to put in the JavaScript method.

Comment: You can't give your input box and the div just below it the same ID, that's invalid in HTML. JavaScript won't be able to tell them apart, which might hinder your script if it can't get the value from the correct element.

Comment: It would be great if you could show us your attempted JavaScript code so we could say for sure if the ids are the problem (you should change them anyway).

Comment: Anyway you easily be able to research how to use JavaScript to get the entered value from a text box and then after that you just need an "if" statement to compare it to the number entered from the model. If they match then you need to update the selected value in the drop-down (again should be pretty trivial to look up how you do that). What have you tried so far?

Comment: P.s as for updating the status in the DB, at the moment your data is going nowhere because you don't have a button to submit your form. In fact, unless you've just omitted it from your snippet, you don't appear to have a form at all.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, a coworker was able to help me with this. I'm sorry I didn't give enough information in the initial question. I really thought there would be an easy way to do this but it seems there is now. Below is the complete code from my view in case someone else stumbles into the same problem.

```
@model IEnumerable<DHLScanner.Models.Device>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LabelPackStationView";
}



@using (Html.BeginForm("LabelPackStation", "Device", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmPackStation" }))
{


<p>
    Find by serial number: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>

<div>
    <h4>Device</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal"></dl>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SerialNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Box Serial Number")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="sp_@item.ID">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SerialNumber)</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="hdn_@item.ID" value="@item.ID" />
                <input type="text" id="ser_@item.ID" oninput="return boxSerialNumberInput(@item.SerialNumber)" />
            </td>
            <td>

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddl_" + @item.ID, name = "ID" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<p id="test"> xyz</p>

<p id="links">
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Prep", "PrepStation", "Order", new { id = ViewBag.Order.ID }, null)
    @{
        if (ViewBag.ShowSystemPackView)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Advance to System Pack", "SystemPackStation", "Order", new { id = ViewBag.Order.ID }, null)
        }
    }
</p>

<input type="hidden" name="testField" value="a value here" id="testField" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdn_Url" value="@ViewBag.Url" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdn_OrderId" name="ID" value="@ViewBag.Order.ID" />
<button id="btn_Refresh" name="pageRefrersh" value="refresh">Refresh</button>
```

}

```
@*<form action="" method="post"></form>*@

<script type="text/javascript">

    function RegisterEvents(){

        $('input[id^="ser"]').blur(function () {

            var Id = $(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val();

            var lbl = $('span[id="sp_' + Id + '"]');

            if ($(this).val() == lbl.html()) {

                $('select#ddl_' + Id).val('3');
            }
        });

        $('button[id="btn_Refresh"]').click(function () {

            CollectDeviceData();

            return false;
        });
    }
    function CollectDeviceData() {

        var devices = new Array();

        // Collect Data
        $.each($('input[id^="ser"]'), function () {

            var Id = $(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val();
            var orderId = $('input[id="hdn_OrderId"]').val();

            var device = {};
            device.Id = Id;
            device.Status = $('select#ddl_' + Id).val();
            device.OrderID = orderId; 

            devices.push(device);
        });

        var jsonObject = {

            devices: JSON.stringify(devices)
        };       

        //Return Data
        var results = function (data) {

            window.location.href = $('input[id="hdn_Url"]').val();
        };
        PostBack(jsonObject, results);
    }
    function PostBack(jsonObject, result) {

        var url = $('input[id="hdn_Url"]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            data: jsonObject,
            success: result,
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        RegisterEvents();
    });

</script>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```